# how to style a button like this

Tags: html, css, button, input

hi there I don't know if this is a question you can answer or not but id like to style a submit button like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJAiG.png)
I don't know much about css so your help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to checkout tutorials on css first, try to attempt to build something next and then ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
.button {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: solid orange 1px;
    color: orange;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code..

HTML

```
<button class="look_btn">Take a look</button>
```

CSS

```
    .look_btn {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #fc8620;
        color: #fc8620;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 8px 23px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        outline: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```css
.sbmtbutton{padding:8px 30px; border:1px solid #FF8830; color:#FF8830; background-color:#F2F2EF;text-transform:uppercase;}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="sbmtbutton">Take a look</button>
```